# Problem in running flutter without android studio on windows

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-manager

i want to try android coding without android studio. i installed android command line tools and have android-sdk platforms like this.i also installed vs code. and flutter as the official docs says. but i have this problem:

[image]

[image]

i also changed the system environment variables.

this is the path of the android command line tools

[image]

and this is the system environment variables :

[image]

this is the platforms folder :

[image]

where is my mistake?

Comment: Maybe the android platform is not installed , if you only installed the command line tools you install them with sdkmanager . Please add a screenshot of your platforms folder

Comment: @ValdaXD added the screenshot of platforms folder

Comment: lol Welcome to flutter world. I faced this problem for 3 days.

Comment: @kam1234 and did you solved the problem? :D

Comment: yes i did but it takes time to solve this problem and i use ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

So it seems like platforms-28 is installed and i believe that it is , and flutter it detecting the folder and telling you that it knows , so the enviroment variable it's also set.

When this happens to me i do the following :

Add the android folder to PATH as well.

Restart the pc[the enviroment variables are kinda weird if i don't do that]

delete the android-28 , the platform tools folder and do and the build tools[wich you don't even have there] , and go to my android/tools/bin [in your case is only tools/bin ] in the command line and launch a whole new `sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28" "build-tools;29.0.0"`

oh and then i `sdkmanager --licenses` to validate all.

then restart again just in case